# How to remove an element in array containing a certain word in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that contains words like 'free advice', 'consulting', 'ask for free' etc. And I want to remove elements that contain the word 'free'. I have the following codes but the output is blank.. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

```
foreach ($myarray as $value){ 
   // remove words containing 'free' 
   if (strpos($value, 'free') !== false) {
             unset($myarray[$value]);
   }
}
```

Comment: You say the "output is blank." The posted code should not generate any output. What output were you expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays have keys and values. You're looking at the values, but trying to unset keys. Unless they match (i.e. your array looks like `['test' => 'test', 'freedom' => 'freedom']`), this isn't what you want. Try this:

```
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value){ 
    // remove words containing 'free' 
    if (strpos($value, 'free') !== false) {
        unset($myarray[$key]);
    }
}
```